# Getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object C#?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

**i am getting Getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object error 

my code and the image are attached below**

```
   public class Backlogitem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public string State { get; set; }
           // public DateTime? due { get; set; }
            public int priorty { get; set; }
            public int Size { get; set; }
          //  public int effort { get; set; }
            public int StoryPoints { get; set; }
            public string DoneStatus { get; set; }
            public string StoryOwner { get; set; }
            public string Assignedto { get; set; }
            public string StoryAuthor { get; set; }
            public string IterationPath { get; set; }

        }
```

[image]
[image: values of the property]

workitemlist image 
[image]
rest of the code is pasted here 
https://github.com/akhiljain1611/TFS/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: According to the highlighted line it's either `workItemList` that is null or the last item in the `workItemList` or the `PBacklog` inside that last item in the `workItemList`

Comment: You should share the code around `workItemList`. Is it initialized? Or `PBacklog`?

Comment: added @FaizanRabbani https://github.com/akhiljain1611/TFS/blob/master/README.md

Comment: You need to initialize `PBacklog`, can you share `workItemList` class as well?

Comment: added https://github.com/akhiljain1611/TFS/blob/master/README.md

Comment: how to do it ? @FaizanRabbani

Comment: in `workItemList` you will have to initialize `PBacklog` like following:

`List<Backlogitem> PBacklog = new List<Backlogitem>;`

Comment: remove the property ?

Comment: Add the code for class `workItemList`?

Comment: yes in github @FaizanRabbani

Comment: Please see my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the lists `(Issues, Tasks and PBacklog)` before you can begin adding items to it. I have done it using a constructor:

```
public class WorkItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public string WorkitemType { get; set; }
    public string Priorty { get; set; }
    public string IterationPath { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public List<TFSIssue> Issues { get; set; }
    public List<TFSTask> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<Backlogitem> PBacklog { get; set;}

    public WorkItemViewModel()  // Added a public constructor
    {
        Issues = new List<TFSIssue>();
        Tasks = new List<TFSTask>();
        PBacklog =  new List<Backlogitem>();
    }
}
```